# CSS - how to put div right to another div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-div">
     <table id="gameboard-table"></table>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
     Waiting for X players to join
     <div> Player 1 - </div>
     <div> Player 2 - </div>
     <div> Player 3 - </div>
     <div> Player 4 - </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The first div has a table that is being created dynamically, that second one is static.

I've tried to use

```css
.main-div {
   float: left;
}
```

but the divs are still one beneath the other.

Of course, I didn't forget to include the CSS file in the HTML :)

How can I solve it?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do they have a set size?

Comment: The divs? no they dont. The first one has dynamic content.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k3zo353q/ (though I had to give `border` and `min-height` to make the `<table>` visible).

Comment: did you try display: inline-block instead of float: left?

Comment: @user3364652 put some content in your table then it will work - http://jsfiddle.net/vfnja2Lx/

Comment: @Mary Melody It's working in this online editor, but not on my computer. :S

Comment: @user3364652 If you have different HTML and CSS code then please post the relevant code in your post.

Comment: The original solution with float:left is working. I think my browser didn't refresh well after each html change. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set their width, because otherwise they just fill to 100%.

```css
.main-div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Try with 49%, sometimes there are margins or borders messing things up.

Comment: Still the same. I've tried to put the two divs in another div, still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Your float-left should be on the child divs of main-div:

```css
.main-div div {
  float: left;
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqe7ug1L/)

Note that the way your HTML is written now, the "Waiting for" text doesn't appear above them. You'll need to wrap that in a separate element so that it appears above the divs (I'm assuming that's the effect you're after).

Comment: I think he wants the `<table>`-containing `<div>` beside the `<div>` with the 'waiting for...' message.

Comment: Yeah. The table should be in a div and the players info should be in another div, right to the table's div.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I updated the Fiddle and put in content for the table. It's appearing that way now: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqe7ug1L/1/. Not sure why it's still appearing incorrectly for you, float: left should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

~10 years ago we didn't have flex and/or grid, nowadays you would solve this with flexbox. Wrap everything in a container div and apply `display: flex` to it. You can adjust the spacing with the `gap` property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-div">
    <table id="gameboard-table">
      <tr>
        <td> TEST</td>
        <td> ASDF </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="main-div">
    Waiting for X players to join
    <div> Player 1 - </div>
    <div> Player 2 - </div>
    <div> Player 3 - </div>
    <div> Player 4 - </div>
  </div>

</div>
```